# Issue when trying to access Solace VMR

Tags: solace

I have a Solace VMR in Azure which was working before.

Though after a restart of the VM, I can ssh to the said server but when running the command `sudo docker exec -it solace /usr/sw/loads/currentload/bin/cli -A` nothing happens and the SolOS CLI does not load.

Also tried to access by SolAdmin, same issue happens as I cannot log in to manage the router.

EDIT: We were not sure on the issue and decided to reinstall a new VMR on a new VM instance.

Comment: is the solacectl command available in the host shell?

Comment: Hi, I tried that command:


`[tptadmin@SolaceVMR0 ~]$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
9aacb8793c6f        solace-app:8.7.0.1022-community   "/usr/sbin/boot.sh"   2 months ago        Up 27 seconds                           solace

[tptadmin@SolaceVMR0 ~]$ sudo docker exec -it solace /usr/sw/loads/currentload/bin/cli -A

[tptadmin@SolaceVMR0 ~]$ solacectl
-bash: solacectl: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Solace container does not restart by itself.

```
$ docker inspect solace
...
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
```

What is your server uptime? You can manually start the container again with

```
$ docker start solace
```